# SSRS create multiple forms from one query

Tags: sql, forms, t-sql, reporting-services

Does anyone know how I can run a single query that will return any number of rows but generate a form for each row returned complete with header and footer?

Imagine I have an SQL database with the names of successful and unsuccessful candidates for an examination. I wish to scan for the successful candidates and insert their name into a certificate. Each candidate gets one certificate with their name on it.

(This isn't what I am actually doing but it's super simplified for explanation purposes, I'm doing shipping certificates and I have written the code to put multiple certificate numbers on a single form. now the Brazilians want one form per certificate).

I'm using Visual studio 2004 and SQL Server 2008 R2 and I can find examples of everything else except how to generate multiple forms.

Anyone know or have a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after a **List** control.

See [Adding a List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for further details and examples.

A List control allow a free-form section to be repeated for each row in a group or Dataset.

In your case you will design the certificate by adding elements inside the List control, which would then be displayed for each row in your Dataset.

You can apply the filtering you require to the List itself or when generating your Dataset.

Comment: I will investigate the list control Thanks Ian.